# php can run the python programm from php shell but not on the webbrowser

Tags: php, python, matplotlib

I have a python script that uses ipyhon and it can be executed when I run it from the terminal using php -a (interactive shell), but when I type localserver/RDMIP_KE.php (test.php is the script wrtten with gedit in ubuntu) nothing happens and I only see a blank page. Any idea why?

```
<?php
$command = escapeshellcmd('/home/administrator/Desktop/RDMIP_KE.py');
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;

?>
```

Just an update: I checked the log file and it gives me a list of errors for example about the pyplot: File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2460,ax = gca() in plot

But again as I said before the python program works fine and can be executed with php if I run it from the php shell. I don't understand what's going on.

Comment: Could it have something to do with the path of the python script relative to the php code running on the server?

Comment: Well I have saved the python file in the www folder where the php file is and ran it again, but no luck!

Comment: Did you change your escapeshellcmd function call accordingly ?

Comment: Your commandline PHP client may use another php.ini than mod_php in your webserver. Can you provide the full error messages you get in the logfile?

Comment: File "/home/administrator/Desktop/RDMIP_KE.py", line 501, in <module>
    rdm_basic_with_2dwindow(raw_dechirped_dec_signal, samp_rate, tm, bw, fc, sv, xax_type, yax_type, RDM_without_averaging, RDM_with_averaging, avg_window_size, avg_window_step_size, revusd)
  File "/home/administrator/Desktop/RDMIP_KE.py", line 57, in rdm_basic_with_2dwindow
    plt.plot(Fk)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2460, in plot
    ax = gca()
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 701, in gca
    ax =  gcf().gca(**kwargs)

Comment: and the program can not be executed from the www folder (even through php shell) so I moved it back to desktop!

Comment: Rest of the errors:LFile "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 343, in figure
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 80, in new_figure_manager
    window = Tk.Tk()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1688, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable